# ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openai-api

When I try to install `openai` on my Google Colab, I get this error:

```
from openai import OpenAI


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5ee9a4e68b89> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from openai import OpenAI

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/_utils/_streams.py in <module>
      1 from typing import Any
----> 2 from typing_extensions import Iterator, AsyncIterator
      3 
      4 
      5 def consume_sync_iterator(iterator: Iterator[Any]) -> None:

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

My details to reproduce:

`Python 3.10.12`

`OS` is `Windows 11`

`typing_extensions` is `4.9.0`

Edit:

my `typing_extensions` details:

[image]

Comment: Better question is why `openai` is importing `Iterator` from `typing_extensions` in the first place. It just re-exports `typing.Iterator`, and `typing.Iterator` has been deprecated in favor of `collections.abc.Iterator` for several years.

Comment: Yes, you are right I am not sure either.

Comment: Can you verify that you are really using 4.9.0? It looks like the re-exports were added for 4.7.

Comment: yes it is `typing_extensions==4.9.0`. I checked.

Comment: some other members also having the same configuration facing the same error: https://community.openai.com/t/error-while-importing-openai-from-open-import-openai/578166/19?u=rubeenatalha313

Comment: That's definitely not typing_extensions 4.9.0 you're hitting there. It's likely you're looking at the packages from a different Python setup than the one you're using.

Comment: Particularly, if you've installed typing_extensions 4.9.0 on your local machine, that won't do anything to affect Colab.

Comment: I will add my screen shot in my question. Just added the screenshot.

Comment: I am not using any virtual machine or any virtual path. Just pure google colab.

Comment: If you do have typing_extensions 4.9.0 installed in this environment, you probably had a lower version already loaded before installing 4.9.0. Upgrading packages while a Python session is running won't affect versions the session already loaded.

Comment: No dear.. `typing_extensions 4.9.0` was already installed before I install `openai`. Please see the link below, a lot of people having `typing_extensions 4.9.0`  faced the same error : https://community.openai.com/t/error-while-importing-openai-from-open-import-openai/578166/12

Comment: openai isn't necessarily what caused typing_extensions to be loaded. If something else loaded typing_extensions first, before you installed the new version, that would cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a related issue on OpenAI forum:

**https://community.openai.com/t/error-while-importing-openai-from-open-import-openai/578166/26**

**Solution 1**:

Credit to @Aymane_oub

```
pip install --force-reinstall typing-extensions==4.5
pip install --force-reinstall openai==1.8
```

---

**Solution 2**:

Credit to @Shannon-21

After navigating through the answers I found that I can change the import of the file that is trying to import Iterator from typing_extensions in this way (On Google Colab):

```
%%writefile /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/_utils/_streams.py
from typing import Any
from typing_extensions import AsyncIterator
from typing import Iterator # import Iterator from the correct library

def consume_sync_iterator(iterator: Iterator[Any]) -> None:
    for _ in iterator:
        ...

async def consume_async_iterator(iterator: AsyncIterator[Any]) -> None:
    async for _ in iterator:
        ...
```

#output
[image]

After running the above code on my colab cell, I was able to use:

[image]

Link to answer : **https://community.openai.com/t/error-while-importing-openai-from-open-import-openai/578166/27?u=rubeenatalha313**